# URL losing plus sign

Tags: php, url

I realize that in a URL, the + symbol represents a space, however I need to keep the plus sign. How can I do this? My URL and code are as follows:

```
http://www.example.com/path/test.php?test=2+2
```

```php
<?php
    $test = $_GET['test'];

    echo $test;
?>
```

This prints out `2 2`.

Comment: There must be a better (canonical) duplicate. That one is for ASP.NET and the answers are specific for .NET. It is mostly about the *how* in .NET, and it has very few details about the encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`+` is interpreted as a space in a URL. To use a `+` you need `%2B`.

http://example.com/path/test.php?test=2%2B2

Comment: Technically correct, but also very narrow. Usually for a particular framework (this is tagged with PHP) there is a ***standard*** function to do it (which also covers more than this single character, `+`).